# What does this error means? Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm totally new in React and had stucked with this error.

Error occurs because of this method:

```
   deleteItem = (index) => {
    this.state.items.splice(index, 1),
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    })
    }
```

I also using @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

If I change button onClick event to this:

```
     onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(index)}
```

it starts working perfectly and i dunno why.

Whole code example

```
import React from 'react';

export default class extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };
};
addItem = () => {
    this.state.items.push('added');
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    });
}
deleteItem = (index) => {
    this.state.items.splice(index, 1),
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    })
}
render(){
    const list = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{item}
        <button onClick={this.deleteItem(index)}>Remove</button>
        </li>
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {list}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Try `onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}`

Comment: OMG, it works. But can u explain why?

Comment: You are immediately calling this.deleteItem and passing the returned value (undefined) of that function to the onClick handler instead of passing a function that will call deleteItem on click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

You are directly mutating the `state`, don't do it. Pass a new state object in the `setState()` method.

```
 deleteItem = (index) => {
    const newItems = this.state.items.filter((ele, idx) => idx != index),
    this.setState({
        items: newItems
    })
 }
```

Or you can use the `Array.prototype.slice()` function, which does not modify the original array as it takes a copy of it in the given range and returns it in a new array:

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
    const newItems = [...s.slice(0, index), ...s.slice(index + 1)],
    this.setState({
        items: newItems
    })
 }
```

Also the `this` context is not set in your `onClick` handler, use a arrow function `() =>` to capture the lexical this:

```
onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}
```

That is necessary as `this` points to the current execution context, if you don't bind `this` to the lexical `this` and when the callback is invoked the `this` won't be referring to your component instance anymore.

Also if you invoke `deleteItem(index)` immediately the handler will point to `undefined` instead of the `deleteItem` reference as the `deleteItem(index)` returns `undefined`.

You need to modify the `addItem()` method as well, where you should form a new array from the added element:

```
addItem = () => {
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat('added')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to a common concept in functional programming - **pure functions** - which helps you write less buggy code. Pure functions have no side effects in that they don't assign new values to variables, and they don't mutate the state of the application. A famous example of a pure function is one that returns the square root of the argument. There's a test you can run in your mind: can you call the function multiple times with the same result/outcome? If it's a pure function, calling it multiple times does not change the result.

In your example, rendering the same content multiple times should be possible without any side effects. Rendering the content should not add or delete any items. If you want this pure function (render) to return a different result, you have to call it with different arguments which are the props and state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mutating your state directly, use `filter` instead:

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    items: state.items.filter((item, i) => index !== i)
  }))
}
```

I've recently wrote a [post](https://claritydev.net/blog/the-most-common-mistakes-when-using-react) about this and other issues when using React.

Also looking at your render code, when you do `<button onClick={this.deleteItem(index)}>Remove</button>`, it will execute `deleteItem` immediately and pass the result of that to `onClick`, however `onClick` expects a function. What you need to do is to wrap it in a function:

```
<button onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}>Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We must not mutate states directly

Instead of

```js
addItem = () => {
    this.state.items.push('added');
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    });
}
```

Use

```js
addItem = () => {
    this.setState({
        items: […this.state.items,'added']
    });
}
```

And Instead of

```js
deleteItem = (index) => {
    this.state.items.splice(index, 1),
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items
    })
}
```

Use

```js
deleteItem = (index) => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    items: state.items.filter((item, idx) => index !== idx)
  }))
}
```

Use latest es6 or latter features of javascript as arrow function, object destructuring, spread operator and other